# What is the scope of this site?

Tags: discussion, scope

There are a number of discussions indicating the scope of this site is wider than it seems.

- [Should we change our name [Redux]](https://communitybuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175)
- [Should we change our name to make implicit that our scope goes beyond mere moderation?](https://communitybuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140)
- [Is our "apparent" scope too narrow? How do we grow this site?](https://communitybuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172)

The [What topics can I ask about here?](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) section of the help, is not helpful

> Please look around to see if your question has been asked before. It’s also OK to ask and answer your own question.
>
> If your question is not specifically on-topic for Moderators Stack Exchange, it may be on topic for another Stack Exchange site. If no site currently exists that will accept your question, you may commit to or propose a new site at Area51, the place where new Stack Exchange communities are democratically created.

What is the scope of this site?

Comment: The moderators can edit the help section (only that page). It has been on my todo list but I haven't had time to craft a meta post.

Answer (score 8):

As I see it, the site is currently operating under the broad scope of being "for community managers, administrators, and moderators". [[1]](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/tour) In addition to that, we also accept questions from a user's point of view. [[2]](https://communitybuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32/should-we-accept-questions-about-moderation-issues-from-users-points-of-view)

We focus on the **community building** aspect, not just moderation of such a community, across multiple platforms [[3]](https://communitybuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7/should-this-site-cater-to-those-trying-to-build-community-platforms) and try not to focus on the technical portion of specific platforms [[4]](https://communitybuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/31/78), but that doesn't mean that technical details can't be provided as part of the answer [[5 (disclaimer, this is my answer)]](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/a/336/78).

We also attempt to provide broader answers and not focus on any specific platform [[6]](https://communitybuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/30/78). This does not mean that there can not be questions *about* specific platforms, but we do try to keep the questions applicable across various communities.

Through all of this, we recognize that we are a more subjective Stack Exchange site and there isn't necessarily one answer to a problem. We do try to limit discussions though, as other subjective exchanges are doing. [[7]](https://communitybuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/48/78)

Comment: So you are saying; "Anything related to online community building of a non-technical nature is in scope"?

Comment: With that scope; I have a couple of questions in mind that are potential "hot network questions" Let me know if anyone would like me to post them before this discussion matures or if you would prefer to discuss it a bit more first.

Comment: You post your questions. If there are concerns they will generate a Meta post. Being a younger beta site means we are still refining our scope. Having "Is X on topic" type questions on meta is very beneficial to nailing down the scope.

Comment: This uncertainty is a tad disconcerting

Comment: Is there a particular aspect you are concerned about? We can clarify if you are more specific

Answer (score 3):

Currently the site is categorised as "professional" by stack exchange.

It would be better placed in "Culture / Recreation" or perhaps "Life / Arts". This categorisation is key to what the site is about.

It's quite clear that the site is not about moderating, it's about communities and the interactions of community members.

Comment: I don't see a connection between this site and Culture/Recreation. Mind you, Politics is classified there, so there's a precedent for interpreting that category in weird ways — I think the name of that category doesn't correspond to what it's intended to cover. Life/Arts is marginal, this site is about the sociological aspects of communication, not about the artistic aspects. Professional is applicable to a large part of the site: moderation and community management are professional activities, even though they're often practiced by volunteers.